# Android change color of messages in listview after its read

Tags: android

I am getting messages from server i want to show it in a list view. After the user read the messages i want to change the color of the Text-view to grey, because i want to differentiate between read and unread messages.

Comment: Am trying the concept..

Comment: Do R&D and try your level best, come here again if you still would be facing issue!

Comment: You need to create customAdapter for this

Comment: Add variable in your modelclass or arraylist set to adapter about message read state and set the color acordingly using simple if else loop

Comment: I have already designed the the custom list view using Baseadapter

Comment: Please past adapter class code

Comment: How to do using Shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `CustomAdapter`. and put condition for read/unread message in `getView()` and change text color as you want.

Just try this

**CustomListAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<MessageData> dataList;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageData> arr) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = arr;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_spinner, null);

    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_spinner_item);

    textView.setText("" + dataList.get(position).getMessage());

    // here you can get Read/Unread status for all message
    boolean isRead = dataList.get(position).isRead();

    if (isRead) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    } else {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return view;
}

}
```

then call like this from mainactivity

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.requestview);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist_pendingtask);

    ArrayList<MessageData> arrMessageData = new ArrayList<MainActivity.MessageData>();

    MessageData data1 = new MessageData();
    data1.setMessage("message 1");
    data1.setRead(true);

    MessageData data2 = new MessageData();
    data2.setMessage("message 2 (unread)");
    data2.setRead(false);

    MessageData data3 = new MessageData();
    data3.setMessage("message 3");
    data3.setRead(true);

    arrMessageData.add(data1);
    arrMessageData.add(data2);
    arrMessageData.add(data3);

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, arrMessageData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class MessageData {

    String message = "";
    boolean isRead = false;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isRead() {
        return isRead;
    }

    public void setRead(boolean isRead) {
        this.isRead = isRead;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: i fetch all the values from database and populate the list view.what ll happen if i kill the application and open.All read messages will turn to unread messages?

Comment: you must set read/unread status in database then no issue